# How to controll chunk size or count chunks in Spanner Stream NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-spanner, stream-processing, node-streams

**Problem:**

We have tried to use Spanner `runStream` to migrate a part of data (the millions of data) by specific query (in **select query** we have used more then one table)

```
 spannerDatabase
  .runStream({
    sql,
    params,
    json: true
  })
```

But after running Cloud functions (256 MB size) for this - I've got `Error: memory limit exceeded.`

**Investigation**

After investigation I've found that `@google-cloud/spanner` use partialResultStream where maxQueued is 10
and it seems that there are not appropriate params to manage chunk size or count of chunks (each chunk response near 100 000 field values)

On the current moment we are trying to use `client.executeStreamingSql` method but there we have a big implementation (like **preparing** params `Struct`, parseChunk like what `PartialResultStream` do)

```
client.executeStreamingSql({
  session: session.id,
  sql,
  paramsType,
  params,
}, {
  pageSize: 1000,
});
```

**Expectation**

We need to decrease the memory consumption when reading from `Spanner`.

UPDATED:

Here is an example of using stream in spanner (we try to write into the file)

```
const { Spanner } = require("@google-cloud/spanner");
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require('util');
const stream = require('stream');
const through = require('through');

const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);

const spanner = {
  "instanceId": "..",
  "databaseId": "..",
  "projectId": ".."
};
const filePath = "./users.data.txt";
const keyFilename = "service-account.json";

const spannerDatabase = new Spanner({
  projectId: spanner.projectId,
  keyFilename,
})
  .instance(spanner.instanceId)
  .database(spanner.databaseId);

const spannerStream = spannerDatabase.runStream({
  sql: 'select * from user',
  json: true,
  gaxOptions: {
    pageSize: 1000,
  },
});

const run = async () => {
  await pipeline(
    spannerStream,
    through(function (data) {
      return this.queue(`${JSON.stringify(data)}\n`);
    }),
    fs.createWriteStream(filePath)
  );

  process.exit(0);
};

run();
```

The memory usage incredibly increase every time when data consuming.
In Spanner user table near 100 000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
     spannerDatabase
      .runStream({
        sql,
        params,
        json: true,
       gaxOptions: {
          pageSize: 1000,
       }
      })
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work (none of these: pageSize, maxResults). I'm still getting a lot of rows in a chunk (near 100 000 values). We can put a break point in partial-result-stream.js (in `isCheckpointFn` and check `row.values.length`). The max memory used was near 200 Mb.

Comment: I see. I'll file an internal bug to track this. In the meantime can you provide more info about what you're trying to achieve?

1. Is this a one time migration? What exactly do you with the results?
2. Can the cloud function memory be increased?
3. What is the size of each row/column?
4. Can you provide a sample query? Could the query be modified to limit the results?
5. Is the workaround you have good enough until the issue is fixed?

Comment: The question was updated. Please, take a look. We are still working on workaround. It seems that we will use `resumeToken` and create readable stream every time when we need the next part data.

Comment: This may be an issue with the Node.js client library and it's being investigated in this [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-spanner/issues/934).